# need a conditional statement for desired output

Tags: if-statement, logic, conditional-statements, truthtable

I need to write a conditional tatement in IF class by using three variable to get some desired output, i have tried many logics with that three variable to get the desired output which i can use in if class but i couldn't succeed, hope anyone can help me with this, 
Thank you
here us the conditional table i need
A                 B            C            result
False      False      False          False
True        False        False        True
True        True        False         False
True         True        True            True
True        True        False          False

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is only true if

1) A is true and B & C are false
2) A, B, and C are true

In other words:

```
if((A & !B & !C) | (A & B & C)){
  print('true')
}
```

The third and fifth row in your table are equal by the way.